# How to use Bootstrap 5 & Sass on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, sass, nuget-package, bootstrap-5

I have installed `Install-Package bootstrap.sass` in ASP .net core 3.1.

It has installed `bootstrap.js` and `scss` folder. But how to compile the bootrap.scss and use that in the _Layout?

I tried to import the bootstrap from scss but it gives me the error as:
[image]

The NuGet has installed the following file:

[image]

Answer (score 28):

You can follow the steps below to **set up Bootstrap 5 SASS** using ASPNET Core.

1. Delete the **/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap folder**:

   - If your application already contains Bootstrap, you will need to delete these files.
2. Choose the **scss folder** and click install:

   - You can **right-click** **wwwroot** and select **Add->Client-Side Library**. Select **unpkg** provider, "**bootstrap@5.0.1**" library.
   - [[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH65K.jpg)
3. You can create a file called **bootstrap.custom.scss** for testing.

   - You can **right-click** the **bootstrap.custom.scss** file and select **Web Compiler->Compile file.**

     - If you **cannot find the Web Compiler option**, you need to [**click this link**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) to **install the Web Compiler tool**, and then **restart** VS.
   - bootstrap.custom.scss

     - ```
       $primary: #00ffff;
       $white:white;
       @import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
       nav.navbar {
           background: linear-gradient($primary, $white)
       }
       ```
   - **Modify the _Layout view**

     - ```
       ... ...
       @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />*@
       <link href="~/css/bootstrap.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       ... ...
       @*<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>*@
       ... ...
       ```
   - **Result**

     - [image]

Comment: Thank you for the other workaround. but my question is specifically related to the nugget package manager.

Comment: There are two ways to add Library files in ASP.NET Core projects([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-library-files))the Add Client-Side Library dialog or Manually configure LibMan manifest file entries.