# Error get-function rgba-css-var is not a valid value for background-color

Tags: css, visual-studio-2019, bootstrap-5, saas, asp.net-core-5.0

I have followed the following steps to set up Bootstrap 5 SASS in the ASPNET Core project.

1. right-click `wwwroot` and select `Add->Client-Side Library`. Selectected unpkg provider, `bootstrap@5.1.3` library.
2. Created a file called `main.scss`
3. Imported following from `bootsrap` in main.scss

The content of the `main.scss` are:

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

4. right-click the main.scss file and select `Web Compiler->Compile` file, the file is compiled successfully, and `main.min.css` and `main.css` are generated
5. Modified `_Layout.cshtml` by adding `<link href="~/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

While loading the pages, the CSS is not generated properly. `bg-dark` or `bg-light` shows the invalid values in `background-color`.

[image]

Also in the visual studio there a 75 warnings from this same file `main.css`.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you follow the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817604/10309381) to configure the Bootstrap 5 SASS with the Asp.Net Core project. It may help you fix the said issue.

Comment: I am following the same answer.

Comment: You could refer to my answer to make SASS work. After that, if you still facing the issue with the CSS then you need to share your SASS code with us. So that we could try to make tests on our side. Also, share your expected result of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I refer to the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817604/10309381) and found that with a few changes it started working.

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I have created an Asp.Net core project with the .net core 6.0 version.

Below are the steps to make it work.

1. After creating the project, I deleted the files in `/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap` folder.
2. Right-click the `WWWroot` folder. Click on `Add-> Clientside library` option.
3. Search for `bootstrap` and select `choose specific files` option. Then check the `SCSS` folder. Modify the Target location as below.

[image]

4. Browse thru `wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/scss` and create a file named `bootstrap-custom.scss`.

```css
$primary: #00ffff;
$white: white;
@import "~/lib/bootstrap";

nav.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient($primary, $white)
}
```

5. Installed the extension below and restart the Visual Studio.

[image]

6. Browse thru `wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/scss` location and right click the file `bootstrap-custom.scss`. Select `Web compiler -> Compile file` option.

[image]

7. It will create a `bootstrap-custom.css` and `bootstrap-custom.min.css` files on the same location. Copy both files to the `wwwroot/css` folder.

[image]

8. Go to the `_Layout.cshtml` file and add a reference to the `bootstrap-custom.css`. Also, add comments to the lines below.

**Note** It's up to you, where you keep the compiled CSS files. You just need to make sure you are passing the correct path in the layout file.

```css
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />*@ <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> @*<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>*@
```

9. Run the project.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You may need to make some changes according to your environment to make it work on your side.

Comment: i did in .net-core-5 exact same thing in visual studio 2019, but still not working.

Comment: @Rashik, Could you please inform us at which step you are stuck? and what exact issue you are facing? it could help us understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: the value for the `bg-color` is not displayed in the browser. Can you see the screenshot of the google chrome I have already attached to the question?

Comment: I would suggest you share your SAAS code. I could try to check on my side whether it correctly produce the CSS file.

Comment: it is already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. Turned out to be the SASS Compiler I was using. I'm running a .NET MVC C# Web App, and had installed [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) VS extension with VS 2019. After discovering the error that was generated with bg-primary I started googling the cause. I found the answer in [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34693#issuecomment-913433302) thread, and switched to using the newer SASS Compiler found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SassCompiler). After compiling the SASS again with the new compiler (which was developed by the same person "Mad Kristensen") the problem was resolved.

So if you're using the same compiler try switching to the newer version. You might be able to use the compiler stated in @Deepak-MSFT answer but I haven't tried that one.